# Dice Rolling Application Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

at the moment I am doing a tutorial on edx.org about Typescript2.
But I need some help with the Self Assessment Lab:

"Now that you have learned the basics of how to use TypeScript, you are going to make a simple dice rolling application to the following parameters:

Use the following types in your application: Array, number, string, Boolean.

Use an enum to declare the possible rolled values (Hint: They don't have to be numbers).

Use a class to create your die, including typed properties for the CSS styles needed (length, width, border, color), and for the value contained within the die.

Create an interface to describe your die's types.

Extend the class with a dieRoller class to create a method for rolling the die.

Create a function to instantiate dice using the dieRoller class, binding elements using the constructor() function.

Create a button to roll all the dice at once.

The finished product should end up looking something like this, and should randomly generate a different value from the enum for each individual die when the "Roll Dice" button is pressed."

There should be four dices and afterwards a button (all in one line).

My problem is that I am not able to create only one button or that i cannot use rolleDice() (if i declare the button outside of the class... usually one would probably declare it outside and create an instance of the class... but no idea how to do this, because the class has a constructor with a parameter).
So maybe you have an idea... Or i just missunderstood the task? :/

Thank your!

```
class diceRoller {
    span: Element;
    constructor(span: Element) {
        this.span = span;
    }
    rolleDice(diceValue: number): boolean {
        (<HTMLElement>this.span).textContent = diceValues[diceValue];
        return true;
    }
}
class dice extends diceRoller {
    button: Element = document.createElement('button');
    constructor(span: Element) {
        super(span);
        (<HTMLElement>span).style.cssText = "border: 5px solid black; display: inline-block; height: 50px;  width: 50px; margin: 2px"; 
        this.button.textContent = "Role Dice";      
        document.body.appendChild(this.button);  
    }
}
enum diceValues {
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five,
    six
}
interface diceTypes {
    span: Element;
}
let Elements: Array<diceTypes> = [];
for (let index: number = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    Elements.push({
        'span': document.createElement('span'),
    });
}
let getRandomIntInclusive: Function = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
Elements.map((elem, index) => {
    let cube = new dice(elem.span);
    let button: Element = document.createElement('button');
    document.body.appendChild(elem.span);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In task said that dieRoller extends die, not die extends dieRoller. Die is just a cube, dieRoller is a cube with a method.

Also I created a separate class for RollButton, it has method that get array with all dice and firing it's rollDice methods.

One thing I'm not sure is there more beauty way not use two separate arrays - for Elements and for diceCollection but just for diceCollection.

In more idealy way I see big class wich contains array of Dice instances and RollButton.

Also it's cool for DiceValues to start from 1.

Anyway it works but refactoring are welcome. http://jsbin.com/rahewuhije/edit?js,output

```
class Dice {
    span: Element;
    constructor(span: Element) {
        this.span = span;
    }
}
class DiceRoller extends Dice {
    // button: Element = document.createElement('button');
    constructor(span: Element) {
        super(span);
        (<HTMLElement>span).style.cssText = "border: 5px solid black; display: inline-block; height: 50px;  width: 50px; margin: 2px"; 
        // this.button.textContent = "Role Dice";      
        // document.body.appendChild(this.button);  
    }
    rolleDice(diceValue: number): boolean {
        (<HTMLElement>this.span).textContent = DiceValues[diceValue];
        return true;
    }
}

class DiceRollerButton {
  button: Element;
  constructor(button: Element) {
    this.button = button;
    (<HTMLElement>this.button).style.cssText = "display: inline-block;";
    this.button.textContent = "Roll!";
    document.body.appendChild(this.button);
  }

  roll(diceCollection: Array<DiceRoller>) {
    diceCollection.forEach((item) => {
      item.span.textContent = DiceValues[getRandomIntInclusive(1, 6)];
    });
  }
}

enum DiceValues {
    one = 1,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five,
    six
}
interface DiceTypes {
    span: Element;
}
let Elements: Array<DiceTypes> = [];

let diceCollection: Array<DiceRoller> = [];

for (let index: number = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    Elements.push({
        'span': document.createElement('span'),
    });
}
let getRandomIntInclusive: Function = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
Elements.map((elem, index) => {
    let cube = new DiceRoller(elem.span);
    // let button: Element = document.createElement('button');
    document.body.appendChild(elem.span);

    diceCollection.push(cube);
});

let diceRollerButton = new DiceRollerButton(document.createElement('button'));

diceRollerButton.button.onclick = (event): void => {
  diceRollerButton.roll(diceCollection);
}
```